# Jpa delete does runs but does not actually delete the object from database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, crud

I have a user class that has the relationship one-to-many with comments and posts. Each user can have many post and comments. Also each post can have many Comments. The problem is when i try to delete the post delete method runs but it does not delete from database. The weird thing is when i not get the user from header and send it to the delete method and send just new User() to the method, it works correctly. I am stuck and i realy your help.

USER CLASS

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;
    private String email;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Post> posts;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Comment> comments;
}
```

POST CLASS

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long postId;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "post", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Comment> comments;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn (name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

POST CONTROLLER CLASS

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/posts")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PostController {

    private final PostService postService;
    private final UserService userService;

    @DeleteMapping("/{postId}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deletePostById (@PathVariable Long postId, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization) {

        Post post = postService.getPostById(postId).getData();
        String email = JwtUtils.getEmailFromHeader(authorization);
        User user= userService.getUserByEmail(email);
        Result result = postService.deletePost(post, user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);        
    }
}
```

DELETE METHOD IN THE POST SERVICE CLASS

```
public Result deletePost(Post post, User user) {

        try {
            if (post == null) {
                return new Result(false, POST_NOT_FOUND);
            }
            else if (user.getUserId().equals(post.getUser().getUserId())) {

                postRepository.delete(post);
                return new Result(true, POST_DELETED);
            }
            else {
                return new Result(false, PERMISSION_DENIED);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return new Result(false, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is because:

1. you have a User->Post mapping that specifies cascade options of
   merge and persist.
2. When you delete a post, you only delete Post and leave the User instance still referencing it

What happens is you remove Post, and when JPA checks all entities in the Persistence unit for other changes, it'll find your loaded User and that it has a reference to the now removed Post instance. The mapping dictates that it must now persist this detached/removed entity instance - so it works the same as if you called

```
em.remove(post); 
em.persist(post);
```

effectively a no-op.

This doesn't occur if you don't load User because if User isn't in the context, JPA won't know it still reference the delete Post. Your code will load User into the context with the find by email lookup, and also trigger it with the post.getUser(). It isn't a good practice to rely on this in your application though, as someone may end up having user in the context, causing more grief debugging complex transactional code to figure this out later on.

When you have bidirectional relationships, JPA states it is up to you to keep those relationships in synch with the database. In this case, the proper approach is to null out/remove the User->Post reference in addition to deleting the Post. You have orphan removal set on that relationship, so you really don't even need to explicitly delete the Post; just dereferencing it from User is enough.

Comment: I tried it. It works but when there are comments that attach that post, when i delete post reference in user and then delete the post it gives me this error: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null], Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: I don't see why you'd have links from a User to comments and then have Posts with links to those same comments, but it seems you likely do and are hitting the same issue you have with posts for those comments. You'll have to decide how you want to handle those comments and maybe not have the User->comments try to cascade all changes to those comments if they are already reachable via User->Posts->comments.